# What effect does madvise(.., MADV_SEQUENTIAL) have on page eviction on Linux?

Tags: linux, memory, system-calls, mmap, virtual-memory

The [man page for madvise](https://linux.die.net/man/2/madvise) says that MADV_SEQUENTIAL indicates "Expect page references in sequential order. (Hence, pages in the given range can be aggressively read ahead, and *may be freed soon after they are accessed.*)" (Emphasis added). I'm wondering how the hint might affect page eviction for a process that accesses the range in a pattern that is not *strictly* sequential.

In my case, I have a memory range and two threads; *each thread* traverses the range in order, but one thread may run ahead of the other. My application could benefit from MADV_SEQUENTIAL's more aggressive readahead, but I'm not sure if the other effect is a good fit. Allowing pages to be discarded after the *second* thread accesses them would enable optimal response to memory pressure, but if they're paged out unnecessarily between the first thread's access and the second thread's access, MADV_SEQUENTIAL would certainly be a net loss. I would assume the tradeoff depends on memory pressure and the size of the gap between the two threads' positions. I know the ultimate answer to VM performance questions is "benchmark it in your application under real world conditions", but I need a mental model too.

Comment: Digging through kernel sources, I see that the effect of MADV_SEQUENTIAL is to set the VM_SEQ_READ flag on the page range, and that VM_SEQ_READ prevents a page from ever being marked as referenced. I don't really know what the implications of that are, other than confirming that MADV_SEQUENTIAL as currently implemented definitely causes pages to be eligible for swapping out sooner.